# Why is the iOS camera shutter sound slightly delayed when taking a photo of my MacBook screen?

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, photo

I'm using `AVCaptureStillImageOutput#captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(_:completionHandler:)` to take a photo in my iOS app. I have a shutter animation that I'm trying to play in time with the camera shutter sound.

I've noticed that when I take a photo of my laptop keyboard, or anything around the room, the camera shutter sounds plays instantly and lines up perfectly with my shutter animation. However, when I take a photo of my MacBook's screen, there is a noticeable delay of around 0.5 seconds between when the photo is taken, and when the camera shutter sound is played.

Any ideas why this is happening?

UPDATE: I realized this was happening because my screen was very bright, so it must be something to do with the exposure setting of the camera.

Comment: What device are you using? If it's a 4s I'm just going to assume it's the processor not being able to focus on the screen, trying to adjust the brightness levels, playing a sound, and playing an animation. But if it's not a 4s I have no idea.

Comment: I'm using an iPhone 6.

Comment: So you can go ahead and cross the processor off from the list of culprits.